# Add column names dynamically to `select` method in SP PnP JS

Tags: 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

In the `select` method of SP PnP JS how can I add column names dynamically?

For e.g. can the below code

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.select("Col1", "Col2");
```

be written something like this (this does not work as`select` method does not take arrays)?

```
var cols = ["Col1", "Col2"];
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.select(cols);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It supports string array. You need to use the "newer" spread syntax as below:

```
var cols = ["Col1", "Col2"];
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.select(...cols);
```

[Spread syntax in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)